# Angular form validation: how to override $invalid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[image]

```
<div class="col-xs-7">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="settings.input">
        checked
      </label>
    </div>
    <div collapse="!settings.input" ng-class="myform.input.$invalid ? 'has-error has-feedback': ''">
      <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputEmail3" name="input" ng-model="settings.input" placeholder="if checked, then do validation" required min="0">
      <span ng-show="myform.input.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KFELtv4csDoHMqAqYRS8?p=preview)

My question is when I set `required` for the `input`, the `form.$valid` will be **false**, But what I want is only when the `checkbox` **checked**, then do `input` validation, So when not checked, even the `input` is empty, the value of `form.$valid` should be **true**

What I purpose is to override the `$valid` of `input`, how to override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has [ng-required](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired) directive that allows to enable required attribute with an expression. Replace `required=""` on `input` with the following:

```
ng-required="settings.checked"
```

[Live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/z48H1mjT3Euzms8VuUPs?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Form field is getting invalid because you had required attribute over input field, so every time that form input field is considered as required. So what you can do is, you should add `required` attribute on form field conditionally by having `ng-required` directive on input with `expression`.

**Markup**

```
<div collapse="!settings.input" ng-class="myform.input.$invalid ? 'has-error has-feedback': ''">
  <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputEmail3" name="input" 
     ng-model="settings.input" placeholder="if checked, then do validation" 
     ng-required="settings.input" min="0"/>
  <span ng-show="myform.input.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" 
   aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FIY52daqScR2PH5xrg2q?p=preview)